# Pluck de Laravel en Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo una función llamada `getLocations()`:

```
public function getLocations() {

    $locations = Location::pluck('name', 'id');

    return $locations;
}
```

Uso esta información en un formulario hecho en blade (plantilla de laravel) y otro en Vue.js, en blade funciona perfectamente, pero como comúnmente lo hago en vue no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui note que solo me envia un array con los datos, pero no como si fueran atributos (como si hace cuando uso un `all` y no un `pluck`), por lo que no se como acceder a ellos, si fuera un `all()` en vue haria algo como `location.id` y `location.name`, pero con pluck no se como acceder a ellos, y como dije anteriormente, debe ser un pluck por el otro formulario.

Comment: ¿Ya probaste alguna forma? normalmente funciona similar, no es más que un objeto.

Comment: He intentado como mencione en la pregunta, algo como location.id, pero no da nada, cuando deje solo location, me retorno "Torre 1", pero al id no puedo acceder

Comment: Por como hiciste el pluck, te va a devolver la 'id' como clave y 'name' como valor, no los nombres de los campos `id:"1", name:"torre 1"`, sino `1:"torre 1", 2:"torre 2"`. Pero no entiendo como quieres acceder desde vue, tendrías que hacer un forEach o v-for con clave/valor.

Comment: A eso me refiero, ya tengo el foreach, pero no se que debería escribir para usar la clave, por que el valor ya lo tengo